# In the swap test, how is the final probability $P(0)$ calculated?

Tags: quantum-gate, quantum-state, swap-test

Does anyone know much about quantum dot product:

Lets say:

$$|\psi \rangle = \frac{|0\rangle_1|\overrightarrow{x_i}\rangle_2 + |1\rangle_1|\overrightarrow{x_j}\rangle_2}{\sqrt 2}$$
$$|\phi \rangle = \frac{\|\overrightarrow{x_i}\| |0\rangle_1 - \|\overrightarrow{x_j}\| |1\rangle_1}{\sqrt Z}.$$

and assume Z is given
$$ Z = \|\overrightarrow{x_i}\|^2 + \|\overrightarrow{x_j}\|^2 $$

Now feeding $| 0 \rangle_1|\psi \rangle_2|\phi \rangle_3$ into the following dot product gate and take a projective measurement in "0" $| 0 \rangle$ in the basis of {$| 0 \rangle$, $| 1 \rangle$}

[image]

Which is essentially $\frac {1}{2}(| 0 \rangle_1|\psi \rangle_2|\phi \rangle_3 + | 1 \rangle_1|\psi \rangle_2|\phi \rangle_3 + | 0 \rangle_1|\phi \rangle_2|\psi \rangle_3 - | 1 \rangle_1|\phi \rangle_2|\psi \rangle_3)$ (1) before measurement.

Now I was told that the Probability of "0" is $P(0) = \frac{1}{2}(1+\frac{\|\overrightarrow{x_i} - \overrightarrow{x_j}\|^2}{2Z})$ (2)

But I cannot derive the steps between (1) and (2), can someone perhaps show me the way?

---

***[Cross-posted on physics.SE](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/638121/58382)***

Comment: Check derivation on Wiki: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swap_test

Comment: Are you sure you write down |ψ⟩ and |ϕ⟩ correctly? 
It seems that they don't have the same dimensions since |ψ⟩ is a 2-qubit state, while |ϕ⟩ is a 1-qubit state.

Comment: @Egretta.Thula here is a a good explanation of what this operation means by Peter Shor https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/5722/9858

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank you @KAJ226

Comment: @Egretta.Thula yeah no problem. I felt the same when I saw this the first time too. I thought there must be something wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that

\begin{align}|\psi \rangle &= \frac {1}{2}(| 0 \rangle_1|\psi \rangle_2|\phi \rangle_3 + | 1 \rangle_1|\psi \rangle_2|\phi \rangle_3 + | 0 \rangle_1|\phi \rangle_2|\psi \rangle_3 - | 1 \rangle_1|\phi \rangle_2|\psi \rangle_3) \\
&= \dfrac{1}{2}  |0\rangle \bigg( |\psi\rangle_2 |\phi \rangle_3 + |\phi\rangle_2 |\psi\rangle_3 \bigg) + \dfrac{1}{2}|1\rangle \bigg( |\psi\rangle_2 |\phi\rangle_3 - |\phi\rangle_2|\psi\rangle_3 \bigg)\\
&= \dfrac{1}{2}  |0\rangle \bigg( |\psi\rangle |\phi \rangle + |\phi\rangle |\psi\rangle \bigg) + \dfrac{1}{2}|1\rangle \bigg( |\psi\rangle |\phi\rangle - |\phi\rangle|\psi\rangle \bigg)\\
\end{align}
I just removed the subscript in the last equation as it's not really needed.

Then we have that

\begin{align}
P(0) &= P(|0\rangle) = \big| \langle 0| \psi \rangle \big|^2 \\
&=\bigg| \dfrac{1}{2} \langle 0 |0\rangle \bigg( |\psi\rangle |\phi \rangle + |\phi\rangle |\psi\rangle \bigg) + \dfrac{1}{2} \langle 0|1\rangle \bigg( |\psi\rangle |\phi\rangle - |\phi\rangle|\psi\rangle \bigg) \bigg|^2 \\
&= \bigg| \dfrac{1}{2} \cdot 1 \cdot \bigg( |\psi\rangle |\phi \rangle + |\phi\rangle |\psi\rangle \bigg) + 0  \bigg|^2 \\
&= \dfrac{1}{4} \bigg| |\psi\rangle |\phi \rangle + |\phi\rangle |\psi\rangle \bigg|^2\\
&= \dfrac{1}{4} \big(\langle\psi| \langle\phi| + \langle\phi|\langle\psi| \big) \big( |\psi\rangle |\phi \rangle + |\phi\rangle |\psi\rangle \big) \\
&= \dfrac{1}{4} \bigg( 2 + 2\langle\psi|\langle\phi| \psi\rangle |\phi \rangle \bigg)\\
&= \dfrac{1}{4}\bigg(2 + 2\big| \langle \psi |\phi \rangle \big|^2 \bigg) = \dfrac{1}{2}\bigg(1 + \big| \langle \psi |\phi \rangle \big|^2 \bigg)
\end{align}

Now, note that since

$$|\psi \rangle = \frac{|0\rangle_1 |\overrightarrow{x_i}\rangle_2 + |1\rangle_1|\overrightarrow{x_j}\rangle_2}{\sqrt 2}$$
$$|\phi \rangle = \frac{\|\overrightarrow{x_i}\| |0\rangle_1 - \|\overrightarrow{x_j}\| |1\rangle_1}{\sqrt Z}.$$

then we have

\begin{align}
\langle \psi| \phi \rangle &=  \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}\sqrt{Z}} \bigg( \langle 0 | 0 \rangle ||\overrightarrow{x_i}|| \  |\overrightarrow{x_i}\rangle_2 - 0 + 0 - \langle 1 | 1 \rangle ||\overrightarrow{x_j}|| \ |\overrightarrow{x_j}\rangle_2\bigg)\\
&= \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}\sqrt{Z}} \bigg(  ||\overrightarrow{x_i}|| \ |\overrightarrow{x_i}\rangle_2 -  ||\overrightarrow{x_j}|| \ |\overrightarrow{x_j}\rangle_2\bigg)\\
&= \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}\sqrt{Z}} \bigg(  \overrightarrow{x_i}  - \overrightarrow{x_j} \bigg)\\
\end{align}

The last equality is the way  $|x_i \rangle$ is encoded, even though you didn't mentioned it, it should be $|x_i \rangle  = \sum ||\overrightarrow{x_i}||^{-1} \ x_i |i\rangle $.

And therefore,
$$ P(0)  = \dfrac{1}{2}\bigg(1 + \big| \langle \psi |\phi \rangle \big|^2 \bigg) =  \dfrac{1}{2}\bigg(1 + \bigg| \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}\sqrt{Z}} \big(  \overrightarrow{x_i}  - \overrightarrow{x_j} \big) \bigg|^2 \bigg)  = \dfrac{1}{2}\bigg(1 + \dfrac{ \big| \overrightarrow{x_i}  - \overrightarrow{x_j}  \big|^2  }{2Z} \bigg)$$